# How to understand this syntax construction in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

What does this syntax `{ ...: ...}` mean? [Example](https://github.com/maenu/gtoolkit-contribution-typer/blob/master/src/pharo/Typer-Core-Examples/TypExamples.class.st):

```
Class {
    #name : #TypExamples,
    #superclass : #Object,
    #category : #'Typer-Core-Examples-OLD'
}

{ #category : #accessing }
TypExamples >> recursion [
    | x |
    x := [ x ].
    ^ x
]
```

Is it a dictionary? I did not find such syntax in the Pharo Cheat Sheet. Is it legal for Playground and for methods body?

Comment: Looks like the doubts about the Tonel format regarding the introduction of non-Smalltalk syntax to the source code were not completely unwarranted.

Comment: No code format from those who are used (chunk, filetree) is actually "pure". None can be executed without parsing before something (e.g. in chunk removing the ! symbols which *are not* part of smalltalk syntax). So, I always found that observation pointless and basically incorrect. Also, your answer does not tries to "answer" the asked question, but to bring here a polemical issue that belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not Pharo syntax at all. It is "tonel" format, which is a code storing format.
It is composed by chunks of STON (Smalltalk Object Notation, sort of JSON for Pharo) and code itself.

And no, this is not "direct-to-playground" code, you need to use a tool to inject it (like Iceberg or Monticello).

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to read a bit more about the Tonel file format, there is a [specification](https://github.com/GemTalk/TonelSpec). It was developed to enable better git support. Smalltalk has used different version control systems before, including the Monticello dvcs which made it slow in embracing git.